# Replacing XML entity (&amp; &lt; &gt; &nbsp;) with a placeholder

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML file like this;

```
<Table>
<Row>
    <Cell>text id</Cell>
    <Cell>First Text&lt;br/&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;br/&gt;</Cell>
    <Cell>Second Text&lt;br/&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;br/&gt;</Cell>
</Row>
.
.
</Table>
```

With using these code, I am sending every text inside of `<Cell></Cell>` to a list variable.

```
tree = ET.parse(file_path)
root = tree.getroot()
list = []
for row in root.iter(tag='Row'):
    for cell in row:
        list.append(cell.text)
```

Problem is `First Text&lt;br/&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;br/&gt;` becomes to `First Text<br/>&nbsp;<br/>`

I want to replace these entity characters with placeholders assigned by myself because I have to replace them to original form later in my program. For Example;

`special character -> [placeholder]
 &lt;br/&gt;       -> [br/]
 &amp;             -> [amp]
 &nbsp;             -> [nbsp]`

Comment: Can you explain your reason for doing this? In most cases, this sort of trickery is not necessary - it comes from a misunderstanding of how to process XML data.

Comment: I am workin on game tranlation and I am sending these text to google translate. Google Translate API fails when it encounter these entity characters. For correct translation I have to remove/replace these entity characters and after translation I have to place them back.  When I collecting text to list, these entity characters changes like &lt; becomes <

Comment: Not familiar with the Google Translate API - in what form does it return the translated text?  List? Dictionary?

Comment: So you want to do the string substitutions _before_ you invoke the XML parser, so that the characer entity substutions don't happen, and you can recover the exact original text. So...what have you tried re: the text replacements? If you post that code, we may be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way to do it. Before XML parsing, I read every line with readlines() then replace entity characters with placeholders after that write line in a new xml file. After translation I can replace them with original forms with using replace().

`First Text&lt;br/&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;br/&gt;` => `First Text[H1][H4][H6][H1]`

```
with open(r"C:\Users\USER NAME\PycharmProjects\FILE TEST\edited_file.xml", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file2:
    pass

with open(r"C:\Users\USER NAME\PycharmProjects\FILE TEST\source_file.xml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file1:
    lines = file1.readlines()
    text = ""
    for i in lines:
        text = i
        text = text.replace('&lt;br/&gt;', '[H1]')
        text = text.replace('&lt;', '[H2]')
        text = text.replace("&gt;", "[H3]")
        text = text.replace("&amp;", "[H4]")
        text = text.replace("&nbsp;", "[H5]")
        text = text.replace("nbsp;", "[H6]")
        with open(r"C:\Users\USER NAME\PycharmProjects\FILE TEST\edited_file.xml", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file2:
            file2.writelines(text)
```